# How to use find and echo to append a file

Tags: linux, unix, find, solaris

Hi this is my filesystem so far, and what I would like to achieve is to append "Hello world" in every text file that has 1 within its name.

root@s11:~/Test# ls -R

.:
A  B

./A:
A1  A2

./B:
B1  B2

What I did so far is

root@s11:~/Test# find  . -iname "*1" -exec echo "Hello World" >>  {} \;

root@s11:~/Test# find  . -iname "*1" -exec file {} \;

./A/A1:         empty file

./B/B1:         empty file

My machine is Solaris 11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you pass to `-exec` is a program to execute and individual arguments. In particular, you do NOT pass a shell command.

However, `>>` is a shell construct, so if you want to use it, you need to run a shell:

```
find . -iname '*1*' -exec sh -c 'echo "Hello World" >> {}' \;
```

Here, the individual arguments being passed to `-exec` are `sh`, `-c`, `echo "Hello World" >> {}`, allowing you to run a shell command.

Also note that I did `-ianme '*1*'` since your question said "has `1` within its name" rather than "ends with `1`".

Answer (score 1):

why not make it easy. Try the following :

```
find / -name '*1' | while read line; do
    echo "Hello World" >> $line
done
```

Upvote if this works for you

Comment: I found this worked better for me as I was dealing with single and double quotes nested already in my echo command.